# How do I know if a graphics card is capable of a high enough resolution or number of monitors?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, resolution, displayport, integrated-graphics

Can I use the single DisplayPort output of the Inspiron 3050 Micro Desktop (Intel HD Graphics of Celeron J1800) to extend across three independent 1080p displays with a Multi-Stream Transport hub? How can I tell if the video card is capable?

I want to build inexpensive three-monitor workstations and I'm not too familiar with DisplayPort or Multi-Stream Transport.

I'm thinking of buying this computer: [Dell Inspiron 3050 Micro Desktop](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-3050-micro-desktop/pd?oc=ddcwsak101w10)

[image: Dell Inspiron 3050 Micro Desktop]

...and this DisplayPort MST hub: [DisplayPort 1.2 to 3 HDMI Multi-Display MST Hub](http://www.accellcables.com/collections/adapters/products/displayport-1-2-to-3-hdmi-multi-display-mst-hub?variant=1245911928)

[image: DisplayPort 1.2 to 3 HDMI Multi-Display MST Hub]

Dell support is useless. The hub's description includes: "The maximum resolution is dependent on ... the graphics and display solution used."

Short of buying and trying, is there any way to know if this will work or fail?

Comment: "How can I tell if the video card is capable?" - By doing research on the iGPU in question.  The iGPU in question wasn't capable when it was knew, it isn't capable by any standards today, and it shouldn't be expected to do anything except display a picture on a screen.  The CPU and it's iGPU was a bottom of the barrel unit when it was new.

Answer (score 1):

You need a video card capable of Disport Port version 1.2 or better.  Anything **Intel HD** will not work for sure.  It probably won't work but, if it did performance beyond the desktop would be awful.

You need to buy something by AMD or NVIDIA with DisplayPort 1.2 support.

If you expect to do any 3D work you will need a high end video card which will eliminate anything cheap.

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply from Accell tech support:

> In order to drive the connected displays in extended mode using the
>   Accell MST Hub, the computer's GPU must support the Multi-Stream
>   Transport (MST) technology, which is part of the DisplayPort v1.2
>   specifications.  Intel HD Graphics of Celeron J1800 does not support
>   MST and therefore will not be able to drive extended displays using
>   the Accell MST Hub.